# Aerospike AMC - Unable to connect

Tags: aerospike

I have a single aerospike node installed on amazon instance which is accessible and works just fine via java client. Now I'm trying to connect AMC to that node, i would return

> Unable to connect - x.x.x.x.x

Aerospike documentation states this

> If the nodes have multiple IP addresses, the clients will see multiple
>   server IPs for each node. Some of the clients (like java) can
>   de-duplicate the duplicate IPs based on node-id. Where as some tools
>   (AMC, asmonitor) may not be able to de-duplicate. Tools like asmonitor
>   may report such scenarios with cluster visibility false error since it
>   sees a mismatch between cluster size and number of server IPs.

Having that i actually do not have multiple IPs and set access-address still doesn't help

on node:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 
          inet addr:172.x.x.x  Bcast:172.x.x.x  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:8134109541 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4845178601 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000

network {
  service {
    address any
    port 3000
    access-address 172.x.x.x
    reuse-address
  }
```

From outside world I connect to 52.x.x.x

Comment: Please can you share your internal and external IP and the URL you are using to connect to AMC?

Comment: it would also be helpful if you can check amc status by doing sudo service amc status

Comment: @BenBates I see web interface, so service is running. only cant add a node to cluster

Comment: May I ask what error you get and which 'type of IP (172.x or 52.x) you are connecting to?  It would also be good if you can share the AMC logs.  Is AMC on the same machine?  If not, have you tested this?

Comment: @BenBates node and amc are on different machines 172.x is not accessible from outside. I use 52.x which get forwarded. When you open AMC web interface first time you have this window "Enter the IP address and service port (default is 3000) for the node to connect to", so i type in 52.x and get "Unable to connect - 52.x:3000". By Java client can connect.

Comment: @BenBates /var/log/amc> cat error.log
2016-01-19 18:18:36 [16623] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2016-01-19 18:18:36 [16623] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8081 (16623)
2016-01-19 18:18:36 [16623] [INFO] Using worker: eventlet
2016-01-19 18:18:36 [16629] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16629
AMC Version: 3.6.4

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101171/discussion-between-ben-bates-and-macchiatow).

Answer (score 0):

You could try running on the server the following command to get the IP address that will be used by AMC for cluster discovery.

```
asinfo -v service
```

if ***access-address*** setting is already set then AMC will use the IPs from that list.  Its possible that your service list contains a private IP that is not accessible externally.

You have two options:

1) add the public IP address to the access-address with the "virtual" suffix.
And modify your security group access appropriately.

http://www.aerospike.com/docs/reference/configuration/#access-address

or

2) Run AMC locally on the same network as the other nodes and access AMC remotely.

hope this helps.